# Fourier transform of measures on $\mathbb{T}$

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm currently working with Fourier transforms of measures on the $\mathbb{T}^n$ (more specifically in dimension two), i.e.
$$
\hat{\mu}(k) = \int_{\mathbb{T}^n} e^{i k \cdot x} d\mu(x)
$$
or something of that form. I am unfamiliar with this theory and would really appreciate a good reference on this topic.

Would anyone be able to point me to a good reference on the Fourier transform of measures over some unit cell? I have found literature for when $\mathbb{T}$ is replaced with $\mathbb{R}$, but am struggling to find a good reference for the requested case.

In case it is relevant, I am interested in the case when $k$ takes values on some lattice.

Comment: Since you want $\mathbb T$, not $\mathbb R$, you should look up Fourier **series** rather than Fourier transform.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Ah yes. I just thought that the general phrase *transform* is used when working with measures. Thank you for the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to Chapter Four of

> **G. B. Folland, *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis*. CRC Press,
> 1995.**

The book really deserves the word "course" in its title.